# Android ListView layout not expaind

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-constraintlayout

I've a simple ListView with a custom adapter. I've modeled items layout with ConstraintLayout. Everything is working fine, except when a certain TextView contains a long text, making it going on the second row and overlapping the next text. How can I make the item to expand vertically, only when needed?

My list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.altervista.realms.biomap.fragments.EditFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recordsListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My adapter layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/record_row"
    android:longClickable="true"
    >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/editRecordDeleteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:text="@string/icon_delete"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editRecordDate"
        android:text="21/06/2015"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editRecordSpecies"
        android:text="Russola Magnificens Russola Magnificens"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editRecordDate"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/editRecordAbundance"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editRecordLocHab"
        android:text="Faggeta acidofila a Luzula Croce di Forcella Piccola"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/editRecordDeleteButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editRecordSpecies"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editRecordTime"
        android:text="14:44"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/editRecordDeleteButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editRecordAbundance"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editRecordTime"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/editRecordDeleteButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How it looks now:

[image]

I'd like to have 3rd item (and 3rd item only) to expand vertically.
Thank you!

**Edit:**

I've noticed that this problem occurs only if the text is slightly longer than the line. Using a longer text cause the TextView to expand, as expected.

It seems to me that it's using the parent width to decide when to expand the layout, whereas it's using the textview width to decide when to go on a new line.

Please notice that the XML for the images below is identical. I've only changed the text string.

[image]

Comment: what about using `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removing `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` property from you `editRecordLocHab` textView solved the issue in my replicated code.

Comment: Thank you! That constraint was needed to set a margin below the last line. Removing it cause the last line to touch the bottom of the view, ignoring the bottom margin. I think ConstraintLayout does not work very well with margins (not the way I expect, anyway :) )

Comment: So it solves the problem that you were facing in the question?

Comment: Yes. I added a padding instead of a margin below the last element and now everything seems to be in the right place. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to know! Maybe you can mark the question as answered?

Comment: I'm sorry. I gave +1 instead of checking it. Done :)